# Непонятки в чпу. Обратный эффект при добавление https редиректа

Tags: .htaccess, https, редирект, чпу

Всем привет. Есть такой .htaccess

```html
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site.info$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://site/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z0-9\-/]+)/?$ /article.php?id=$1 [L]
```

некое подобие ЧПУ. с site/article.php?id=1 редирет на site/1 
Который в принципе исправно работает и меня это устраивает. Но вот когда я добавляю строки для редиректа на https. То чпу этот работать начинает противоположно. Я захожу на site/1 а редир идет н site/article?id=  в чем может быть проблема?. Вот код .htaccess

```html
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site.info$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://site.info/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z0-9\-/]+)/?$ /article.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ответ. Сначало нужно ставить редирект. А потом ЧПУ тогда все работает.Глупый вопрос получился)